# How to Perform Invoice Capture in Magento2 Programmatically

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, magento2.1.0

How to capture payment for the created invoice. In Magento1.x it is like

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/Service_Order', $this->getOrder())->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
```

I have the order `increment id` which has order status `pending`. Invoice needs to be generated for that order by loading `increment id` and do invoice capture operation. I am expecting the invoice capture operation will set transaction id(Ex. 2121) and move the order status to `completed`

Comment: Full Details explanation to capture invoice, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-invoice-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's pretty similar to M1 in Magento 2, you need to inject the `Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService` in your class:

```
protected $_invoiceService;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    ...
}
```

Then, assuming you have the order you can do:

```
$invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
```

To set a transaction ID on an invoice you can simply call `setTransactionId()` method on the invoice object.

Comment: is it possible to set custom transaction id in invoice capture

Comment: @blakcaps see my update

Comment: Good It helped me

Comment: can we capture the payment after generate the shipment instead of invoice?

Comment: i tried this but shipping fees are not included in the paid amount. any advice ?

Comment: Another problem is, that the transaction seems to not be saved so it cannot be refunded

Comment: A problem of Raphael's answer is, that the transaction seems to not be saved so it cannot be refunded later. You additionally need to save the order and the invoice.
See https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento-2-module-updated/